# Login Popups for SharePoint around Images

Tags: 2007, permissions

We recently made a copy of a Site collection to a new load balanced frontend server. the FARM is now running on IIS 7 and on a Office Server 2008 environment with SharePoint 2007.

All security is correctly setup but with no apparent reason we sometimes are forced to Login again a few times after each other (Even ADMIN user on the server). If cancelled it seems to not bring back some images on the dashboard and landing page. These Images along with all other content had libraries with permissions correctly setup.

we are using s a F5 device to do the loadbalancing since we are running the servers virtually.

Has someone came upon a similar behaviour in their Windows Server 2008 IIS 7 environment? 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you configure special alternate access mappings?

Comment: It seems as if it might be to do with the f5 device. thanks for the advice so far. 
http://www.sharepointdev.net/sharepoint--general-question-answers-discussion/mutiple-logins-required-when-accessingnavigating-sharepoint-web-site-using-public-url-18371.shtml

Will keep looking.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what 'SharePoint 2007 R2' is, but have you had a look using a HTTP Debugger such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/version.asp)? It may provide some insight in where the requests are going to and what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same behavior once, but it was for images stored on the NTFS system. There the permissions were messed up, I never figured out why.

http://koenvosters.wordpress.com/2009/06/18/authentication-problem-on-moss-login-box-keeps-popping-up/

Answer (score 0):

As suspected our F5 (loadbalancer) was the problem. This was caused by the OneConnect Profile set on the F5 device. This must be changed not to be be on Oneconnect.